# Laravel index.php and basic htaccess redirection rules conflict

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

Here I have what I think is a complex problem (not an htaccess expert or even close), so I'll try to give you all the context and be clear about it.

Laravel 9.x contains a default htaccess that look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, Laravel has this thing, if you use the already known *www to non-www* redirection rules, you'll arrive to the index.php URL. This means your users can easily navigate through your website like this:

https://myfakedomain.com/index.php/any-url

For SEO purposes this is a nightmare. And among many propositions, the only *solution* it worked for me is the next one:

```
# index.php redirection
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Finally the problem and my question, in some cases I need to redirect either http to https or www to non-www or viceversa. But I've just found out that my index.php *solution* is messing up with those rules. For example the very well known:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Doesn't work anymore, I mean it works because it redirects properly, but always to the index page.

The behavior of

https://www.myfakedomain.com/any-url

goes to

https://myfakedomain.com

instead of

https://myfakedomain.com/any-url

I need to be able to redirect any subdomain or protocol URL's traffic to the new one avoiding index.php to be shown at the same time.

In case you need it, my full htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# index.php redirection
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# HTTPS redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# www to non-www redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# mail redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: you must redirect to your specific variant of url in the apache or nginx virtual host file.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "specific variant", and do you think is should come from there? Thinking that I work with many clients with different types of hosting enterprises and I don't always have access to virtual host file